# find largest product in a directed graph

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

My question is similar to finding smallest path (Dijkstra's Algorithm), but instead of shortest path, I want to find the largest product of all edges on the one from one node to any other.

Given all edges are positive weighted and each node is bi-directional connected with adjacent nodes, my understanding is that implementation of such algorithm is just the opposite to finding shortest path.  but I am not sure if what i'm thinking is correct, and can anyone suggest where I should start with in C# ? ?

To give an example of bidirectional conncetion:

Node: A,B
Weight: A->B =2;B->A=1/2

so the weight of edges for one node is always reciprocal

Comment: Your description is not very clear, but note that the longest path problem (which is similar to what you are asking here) is NP-hard. So there isn't (probably) a polynomial time algorithm to solve it.

Comment: How about: instead of calculating the product of the weights, calculate the sum of log2 of the weights? This will make your algorithm closer to Dijkstra (though, it will still yield the shortest path and not the longest path... perhaps you should first replace every weight 'W' with its inverse '1/W')

Comment: actually, one of two Weight in bidirection is reciprocal always. but i think your suggestion is very inspiring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All weights are positive, right?

1. Replace each weight W with log(1/W).
2. Run the Bellman-Ford algorithm, which is the extension of Dijkstra for graphs with negative weights.

Comment: does bi-directional connectoin affect result in this case?

Comment: Well, if you have even ONE pair of nodes that are bi-directionally connected, then you have a circle for which the product is infinite, right? Does that circle count as a path? If yes, then that circle is your answer. But if you have several such circles, then the question becomes somewhat irrelevant, as you cannot assert which infinite value is the largest...

Comment: hmm, the circle dose count, doesnt Bellman-ford will end after finding all circles and find smallest cost circle then stop??

Comment: Well... Not really sure how Bellman-Ford and Dijkstra handle circles. I guess that for Dijkstra it's not an issue, because it searches for the shortest path in a graph with non-negative weights. In any case, I realized that my previous comment on "2-node" circles in your graph is irrelevant, as these circles yield 1 (= w * 1/w) and not infinity.

Comment: I dont quite understand, Dijkstra use sum of all weight along the route to find smallest cost, why cant we just change sum to product of all inversed weights on the route? isnt that more directly solve this issue? because the smaller of each product yeilds the smaller of total product.

Comment: Well, the problem with products, is that they tend to grow (or in your case, diminish) relatively fast. And so once the value reaches your CPU's maximum FP precision, it will just turn zero. This is, however, an implementation problem. Other than that, I'm not sure that there is any theoretical problem with your suggestion.

Comment: got it, great help, i think I will try to implement both to see how different they are. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Why replace $W$ with $log(1/W)$? Bellman-Ford algorithm outputs a list of distance of the current nodes. How can we find the largest product?